# How can I determine if a request is for a static resource in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, httprequest

I'm writing a logger to log each request in Spring, but I don't want to log any static resources like CSS, JS, images, or anything similar.

I thought about just checking extensions, but there are a few cases where static content files don't have extensions, and I don't want to log them. I could also check the header, but I want the logger to be as fast as possible and I'd have to do some kind of string comparison or parsing, which I want to avoid if possible since this (and future) application will be handling a high number of requests.

I am basically looking to log anything that isn't a static resource request, as I'd potentially like to use this same logger in web services as well as front-end applications.

So is there a way to tell if a request is for a static resource? I know Spring specifically requires mapping to a resource handler. Is there any way to know if the request has somehow been handled by the resource handler?

Comment: If you do this through i.e. a filter I would guess that you can use the path and just log requests to your context path based on this. I.e. by using [HttpServletRequest.getServletPath](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getServletPath())

Comment: Right, though how can I know if that is a static resource as defined by the ResourceHandlerRegistry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was able to resolve this in a fairly clean way using Spring's `MediaType.parseMediaTypes(String)`

I was able to assume the request type by checking the 'accept' field in the request header. I determined what `MediaType`s were acceptable, and then put them in a `HashSet`, e.g.

```
mediaTypeSet.add(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
```

Then I just iterated over the results from `parseMediaType` to determine if it was a request I wanted to log.

```
boolean shouldLog(HttpServletRequest request){
  String acceptHeader = request.getHeader("accept");
  if(acceptHeader != null){
     List<MediaType> mediaTypes = MediaType.parseMediaTypes(acceptHeader);
     for(MediaType mediaType : mediaTypes){
        if(mediaTypeSet.contains(mediaType)) return true;
     }
  }
  return false;
}
```

There are occasions where the accept header reads `*/*` so it's expecting anything, but in my case, the requests I was interested in all had defined MIME types.